# How can I add machines to data already been sharded in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, sharding

I have a lot of data of users. Each one has a unique user id which is represented by a base64 of six characters. for example (Fga6=gY).
I used a hash function to spread the users across my MySQL machines.

I have four machines, so when I want to save a new user, I just check on which server i should save it:

```
hash(userId) % 4
```

My question is how can I add more machines in case I have too much load on the 4 machines.
if I will start using 6 machines and use modulo 6 instead of 4 it will work for new users. but when try to query old users my application server will be forwarded to the wrong machine.

How can I solve it for a system that is already in production?

How can I plan a system better to allow me to scale out the machines whenever it's needed?

Comment: To answer the "how can I plan a system better to allow scale-out" question, [consistent hashing](https://www.mikeperham.com/2009/01/14/consistent-hashing-in-memcache-client/) is a good place to start!

Comment: An alternative that involves no reallocation is to have an "orchestrator" (probably backed by a database) that tracks where each account is stored. You'd then use it instead of your hash + mod function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too bad you did not ask *before* implementing that simple hash.

**First**

I strongly recommend writing a script to move one user from one shard to another shard.  It will be an important component in most of all the following advice.

**Alternatives to Hash**

A "dictionary lookup" is where you have the users listed in a table, together with which shard they are on.  This allows for moving an individual user from one shard to another.  (The details of such a "move" may be quite complex.)  This allows a variety of good things:  Moving a few users from a busy server to a less busy one; adding a new shard; outfitting a new shard, then move users to the new server.  Etc.

A compromise between the "dictionary" and the "hash" works like this:  Hash the user_id into, say, 512 possible values.  Then use a dictionary of only 512 entries to find what shard those users are on.  This requires moving a set of users, not just a single user, but keeps the dictionary at a fixed size.

In either case, the "dictionary" needs to be propagated to all clients for them to use.

**Small help**

Rehashing involves moving essentially all the data around.  This is quite costly in downtime.  Instead, ponder this.  Hash mod 8 (specifically 2*4).  Then split *one* shard into two servers.  This gives pain for only 1/4 of the users.  Actually, with the "move one user" script, only 1/8 of users will be impacted.  There is, of course, some amount of code in the clients to understand that some shards have 1/4th of the users; some have 1/8th.  (This leads you from 4->8, and not your requested 4->6.)

**Alternative topology**

If you clients are on the same servers as the shards, consider moving the app code onto other servers.  That is, have only MySQL on the database shards; have other stuff on other servers.  And configure them differently (RAM, IOPs, etc) if needed.  Your system may actually need more than 4 or fewer than 4 client machines for the load in question.  This topology allows scaling each separately.

**Optimization**

Do you have the slowlog turned on?  With a low value for `long_query_time`?  Run `pt-query-digest` against that log.  Then, let's discuss the first few queries.  They *may* be running slower than they could be.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

This might let you postpone adding a shard.